# Что это за синтаксис внутри html <a>[[${...}]]</a>?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-security

Извините за странную формулировку вопроса, просто я не знаю как это описать.

У меня есть Java Spring проект с использованием Spring Security. В этой кнопке `<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/login">[[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]</a>` высвечивается имя пользователя, который авторизовался (spring security). Если пользователь не вошел, тогда `[[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]` будет возвращать пустую строку "".
Объясните, пожалуйста:

1. Что это за синтаксис такой [[${}]] - это синтаксис Spring`а, Java или ThymeLeaf?
2. Как изменить эту строчку так, чтобы, если пользователь не авторизовался, то в кнопке высвечивалась не пустая строка, а какая-нибудь определенная, например "Sign in". То есть мне нужно что-то вроде if-else в html.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, ${} - синтаксис JSTL (вставка java-кода в html)

Comment: [10. Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну видимо, это синтаксис Spring'а ([ссылка](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) на источник).

`<a>[[${(#httpServletRequest.remoteUser == null) ? "Sign in" : #httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]</a>` - правильная запись условного выражения (я не нашел ничего в интернете, просто наугад писал и на какой-то раз все получилось)